# How to get the equation of a circle tangent to two other circumferences and one axis at the same time?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**I repeated this question in a better way: [Plane-geometry problem with circles and tangents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022813/plane-geometry-problem-with-circles-and-tangents)
I ask the moderator to delete this post.**

I have a doubt in plane geometry. In the book of a problem there is the following Math Figure asking to find the equation of the circle which is tangent to the x-axis and the other two circumferences at the same time. The semicircle has radius = 1. The Geogebra, points R = 0.25
Already tried to solve in various ways, but never get to a result stated.

[image: graphical representation obtained with Geogebra]

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

Any circle that is tangent to a given circle and a given line has its center on a parabola, hence you can find your circle by intersecting two parabolas, for instance. The radius of such a circle can be found through Descartes' circle theorem.

Comment: Ok. I will go to try it. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure Descartes' circle theorem quite works here as the line is the diameter of the semicircle, i.e. intersects it twice rather than being a tangent

Comment: Yes, it works, a line can be seen as a circle with infinite radius, or zero curvature.

Comment: *a line can be seen as a circle with infinite radius* - If only the Inquisition would have been aware of this, they would never have persecuted Galileo... :-$)$