# Plane-geometry problem with circles and tangents

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I have a problem that even my smartest colleagues were able to solve. This is to get the radius of the smallest circle in the drawing below. Using a computer program, I managed to get that lightning is 0.25 cm, but I can not prove this with calculations. I could not solve with the Descartes Circle Theorem, because the three circles are not tangent to each other at all possibilities.
Sorry for my imperfect English, because it is my second language. :-)

$\epsilon_1=-1, \epsilon_2=2$ and $\epsilon_3=\epsilon_4=\frac{1}{r}$

$2((-1^2)+2^2+\frac{1}{r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2})=(-1+2+\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r})^2 \; \rightarrow 2(1+4+\frac{2}{r^2})=(1+\frac{2}{r})^2$

$2+8+\frac{4}{r^2}=1+\frac{4}{r}+\frac{4}{r^2} \; \rightarrow \; \frac{4}{r}=9 \; \rightarrow \; r=\frac{4}{9}= \mathbf {0.\bar{4}\neq 0.25}$

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

[image: Imagem do problema]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E$ has coordinates $(s,r)$
$s^2+(0.5-r)^2=(0.5+r)^2$, so $s^2=2r$
$s^2+r^2=(1-r)^2$ so $2r+r^2=1-2r+r^2$, and $r=1/4$

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!! I lost a very long time trying to work it all possible complicated ways. Then you made me discover that the answer was in front of my eyes all the time. Excellent reasoning.